# Social sharing for Instagram, Pinterest, Facebook, Twitter Cordova

Tags: instagram, pinterest, cordova-3, socialshare

I have already follow this guide from **https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin for Social sharing for Cordova application**. It is working fine for FB,Twitter.
**But I am in need of share to Pinterest and Instagram**

Please help me. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For Instagram try https://github.com/vstirbu/InstagramPlugin which loads a canvas image into the instagram editor.

For Pinterest try https://github.com/realizedmobile/cordova-Pinterest

But this means you will have a few plugins different for sharing, when ideally these would be wrapped together in EddyVerbruggen's plugin.

Comment: I have implemented instagram plugin and its working but when sharing complete its not return to phonegap app (because its open instagram app installed in device). Please help me on this. I have tried this on ios device.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Pinterest, but Instagram does not allow content (media) to the published via the API directly, only comments/likes etc. You can launch the Instagram app on a device to publish media, but from the description of your project that doesn't sound like what you want to do

Comment: I want to share a image and a link to Instagram. Is there instagram api is available or not? If available send me the api url. Please help me.

Comment: Instagram does not allow content (media) to the published via the API . See http://instagram.com/developer/ for what you can do via the API

Comment: @SteveCrawford How do I use the Plugin? Where do I get the clientId?